# What is the best way to publish free and paid vesions of same app on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I have requirement to keep both free (limited features) and paid versions of my android app on Google Play store.

What is the best way to do this? 
Can I use single APK in anyway? 
Do I have to manage two projects in my development environment because of having different package names?

Comment: Integrate inAppPurchase, no need to maintain two app

Answer (score 0):

Use the licensing library and make the paid features an in app purchase that are disabled until bought.

Comment: can you explain more ?